# Notification forwarding from iOS to Bluetooth LE device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question about how to send notifications to a Bluetooth LE device from iOS. I know that it is possible to "subscribe" to the notification service and receive all notifications, but is it possible to filter the notifications in iOS before sending it over to the BLE device?

For instance to filter so only call notifications are sent to the BLE device?

From what I understand Android has this functionality, and I wonder if iOS has the same? The reason is that we want to keep the BLE device as simple as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer to your question? I'm also trying to find more info on this subject and I'm kinda stuck. How can a BLE device subscribe to receive all the notifications?